# Is it possible (and how) to add ConnectionString to app.config at runtime in C#?

Tags: c#, connection-string, app-config

I have a console application which gets the connectionstring as a parameter. I would have to set a ConnectionString in app.config with name 'ConnectionString' and the given parameter as the sql connectionstring.

Thx to answers. With help of the links I got to this:

> var config =
>   ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
>   var connectionStringSettings =
>       new ConnectionStringSettings("ConnectionString",
>   _arguments["connectionString"], "System.Data.SqlClient");
>   config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Add(connectionStringSettings);
>   config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
>   ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");

Answer (score -6, accepted):

IGNORE THIS ANSWER AND SEE BELOW....

Yes - have a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SystemConfiguration.aspx).

This method is probably what you are after

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Add(new ConnectionStringSettings("new name", "new string");
```

Comment: -1, this will result in `System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException : The configuration is read only.`

Comment: How can this be the accepted answer when it clearly doesn't work! Is there some trick that makes this *not* throw an exception? -1 from me for now

Comment: this single line of code is OK.  Its the code before and after thats missing :-)  OPen and save ????

Comment: even missing closing parenthesis.

Comment: I cannot delete this answer as its marked as accepted. Upvoted cubski and edited answer to reflect

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can definitely add/modify/remove settings in the app.config at runtime. This is how I usually do it.

```
using System.Configuration; // don't forget to add the system.configuration dll to your references.

    public static void CreateConnectionString(string datasource, string initialCatalog, string userId, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            //Integrated security will be off if either UserID or Password is supplied
            var integratedSecurity = string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password);

            //Create the connection string using the connection builder
            var connectionBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                DataSource = datasource,
                InitialCatalog = initialCatalog,
                UserID = userId,
                Password = password,
                IntegratedSecurity = integratedSecurity
            };

            //Open the app.config for modification
            var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            //Retreive connection string setting
            var connectionString = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"];
            if (connectionString == null)
            {
                //Create connection string if it doesn't exist
                config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Add(new ConnectionStringSettings
                {
                    Name = ConnectionName,
                    ConnectionString = connectionBuilder.ConnectionString,
                    ProviderName = "System.Data.SqlClient" //Depends on the provider, this is for SQL Server
                });
            }
            else
            {
                //Only modify the connection string if it does exist
                connectionString.ConnectionString = connectionBuilder.ConnectionString;
            }

            //Save changes in the app.config
            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //TODO: Handle exception
        }
}
```

Hope this helps.